# removing rows of groups using a condition based on another row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of movies that looks like this:

```
Index  Movie                   Rotten Tomato Score  Director             Ranking
1      Batman Rises            87                   Christopher Nolan    1
2      Interstellar            73                   Christopher Nolan    2
3      Legally Blonde          71                   Robert Luketic       1
4      The Ugly Truth          14                   Robert Luketic       2
5      (500) Days of Summer    85                   Marc Webb            1
6      The Amazing Spider-Man  71                   Marc Webb            2
7      Wide Awake              45                   M N Shyamalan        1
8      The Last Airbender       5                   M N Shyamalan        2
```

I have made a ranking column which shows the order of ranking based off of the rotten tomato percentage. This is grouped by Director of the movie.

What I am trying to do is to use the ranking column, to drop the lower ranked movies if the top ranked movie is scored above a certain point (50%). For example, For Marc Webb, the only film I want showing for him is (500) Days of Summer, however I would want to show both the movies for M N Shyamalan. The ideal table would look like:

```
Index  Movie                 Rotten Tomato Score  Director             Ranking  
    1  Batman Rises          87                   Christopher Nolan    1      
    3  Legally Blonde        71                   Robert Luketic       1
    5  (500) Days of Summer  85                   Marc Webb            1
    7  Wide Awake            45                   M N Shyamalan        1
    8  The Last Airbender    5                    M N Shyamalan        2
```

I have attempted:

```
movie_names = movie_names.groupby('Movie').filter(lambda g: (g.score <= 0.5).any())
```

However that removed both of M N Shyamalan's movies.

Would anyone know how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Code

```
# is movie score > 50?
m = df['Rotten Tomato Score'] > 50

# Does director has at least one movie with score > 50?
cond1 = m.groupby(df['Director']).transform('any')

# flag the duplicate rows and keep the movie with highest score
cond2 = df.sort_values('Rotten Tomato Score').duplicated('Director', keep='last')

# Drop rows when cond1 and cond2 is met
df[~(cond1 & cond2)]
```

#### Result

```
   Index                 Movie  Rotten Tomato Score           Director  Ranking
0      1          Batman Rises                   87  Christopher Nolan        1
2      3        Legally Blonde                   71     Robert Luketic        1
4      5  (500) Days of Summer                   85          Marc Webb        1
6      7            Wide Awake                   45      M N Shyamalan        1
7      8    The Last Airbender                    5      M N Shyamalan        2
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Index':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                 'Movie':["Batman Rises", "Interstellar", "Legally Blonde", "The Ugly Truth", 
                          "(500) Days of Summer", "The Amazing Spider-Man", "Wide Awake", "The Last Airbender"],
                 'Rotten Tomato Score':[87, 73, 71, 14, 85, 71, 45, 5],
                 'Director':["Christopher Nolan", "Christopher Nolan", "Robert Luketic", "Robert Luketic", 
                             "Marc Webb", "Marc Webb", "M N Shyamalan", "M N Shyamalan"],
                 'Ranking':[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                 })
    
r = (df.groupby('Director')
       .apply(lambda g: (g.sort_values('Rotten Tomato Score')
                          .drop_duplicates(subset='Director', keep='last')) \
                          if g['Rotten Tomato Score'].max() > 50 else g
                         )
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       )

print(r)
```

**Result**

```
   Index                 Movie  Rotten Tomato Score           Director  Ranking
0      1          Batman Rises                   87  Christopher Nolan        1
1      7            Wide Awake                   45      M N Shyamalan        1
2      8    The Last Airbender                    5      M N Shyamalan        2
3      5  (500) Days of Summer                   85          Marc Webb        1
4      3        Legally Blonde                   71     Robert Luketic        1
```